# Using keyboard causes every program to freeze

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, freeze, troubleshooting

I have an odd issue.  Every time I touch the keyboard, whichever program that has focus freezes.  This wasn't happening earlier today; it only started after I ran Windows Update.

My specs:

- Asus m5a97 r2.0 motherboard
- AMD FX-8350 4Ghz x8
- 16GB RAM
- Nvidia GTX 970
- Windows 7 x64
- PS/2 Keyboard *(I don't have a USB keyboard to test with)*

I tried all the usual things: `chkdsk`, `sfc /scannow`, etc.  Nothing reports any errors.  All my drivers are up to date, and I have no pending updates in Windows.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with the updated Broadcom Bluetooth drivers downloaded by Windows Update.  After uninstalling my bluetooth drivers, the issue went away.

I found the solution [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/all-programs-stop-responding-when-typing-any/f4349359-2c2e-469b-ab10-70dedb962d09?auth=1).  It seems the issue has occurred to *a lot* of people...